# Angular2 async pipe not working in ngfor

Tags: typescript, angular, ngfor

I am experiencing a problem with async pipe in Angular2, when I use it inside a `*ngFor`.

Here some code:

This is the template

```html
<li *ngFor="#obj of _filtersPageState | async">
        hello world
</li>
```

The `_filtersPageState` variable is declared as:

```
private _filtersPageState: Observable<any> = new Observable<any>();
```

and it is initialized by using the `select` function of `@ngrx/store`:

```
this._filtersPageState = store.select('FiltersPageState');
this._filtersPageState.subscribe(v => console.log(v));
```

The `FiltersPageState` object inside the store is populated through a http request and if I print the `@ngrx/store` object in the console log, I can see that the get request is correctly performed.

My problem here is that when the `async` pipe is placed inside the `ngFor`, the component fails to load and I get no errors in the Chrome console.

If I write `{{_filtersPageState.value | async}}` in the html template, the value of the `Observable` is displayed correctly.

I'm playing with beta 13

Any clue or suggestion? Thank you!

**Edit**

I noted that if I write `{{_filtersPageState| async}}` inside the template and in the same time I write an `ngFor` (even doe this one cycles on a simple array without `async` pipe, my component breaks (silently)

**Edit 2**

I want to add another tile to the puzzle.

The following template breaks the Component:

```
{{_filtersPageState | async}}
<li *ngFor="#obj of simpleArray">
        {{obj}}
</li>
```

It's like if `async` and `ngFor` don't want to be together :(

**Edit 3**

I found out that no pipe is working inside ngFor:

```
<h1 *ngFor="#element of filtersPageState|async">{{element}}</h1>
<h1 *ngFor="#element of simpleArray|uppercase">{{element}}</h1>
<h1 *ngFor="#element of simpleArray">{{element|uppercase}}</h1>
<h1 *ngFor="#element of simpleArray|aaaaaaaaa">{{element}}</h1>
```

in all four cases (also with `aaaaaaaaa` that is a non existing pipe), my Component fails to load with no error.

Comment: What type does `store.select('FiltersPageState')` return? `ngFor` expects an iterable, so it might just not be one. I've done something very similar in my blog post about this here: http://lukajcb.github.io/blog/angular2/2016/04/02/frp-in-angular-2.html

Comment: `store.select()` returns an observable with an array inside. I will look at your post, thank you. Anyway I edited the question adding more details

Comment: Can you create a Plunker that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.

I was including in the minified version of Angular 2, once I included angular2.dev.js, everything started working.

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't make sense as an acceptable answer, though. :/ Dev or prod version of angular should not create two separate outcomes. Hmmm...