# angular2 viewing observable with async pipe not rendering

Tags: angular, rxjs5

I am using `@ngrx/store` and I am grabbing a slice of the state from the store.

I have a component that wants to display that slice. However, with the `{{ obs$ | async}}` present in the template, the entire template is not rendered. If I remove the `{{ obs$ | async }}` then `SLICE:` is rendered.

Any idea on why this is the case or how to diagnose the issue? The JS console isn't showing me any errors.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'slice',
  template: `SLICE: {{ obs$ | async }}
})
export class Slice {
  obs$: Observable<any>
  constructor(private store:Store<any>) {
    this.obs$ = this.store.select(s => s.slice);
  }
}
```

Comment: I posted my (now deleted) answer without noticing that you've said there aren't any errors in the console - either that's not true, or you *do* have `pipes:[AsyncPipe]` in your component metadata, because otherwise your use of an unimported pipe would definitely throw...

Comment: I added the `pipes: [AsyncPipe]` but to no avail. console definitely doesn't show any errors. It may be due to something unrelated and it's manifesting itself in this way.

Comment: bingo. Unless `AsyncPipe` is globally available now (would be news to me), that shold be throwing without the import, and if it isn't then something somewhere is very wrong. As a sanity check, try replacing `obs$  | async` with `obs$ | gibberish` in the template and see if that throws

Comment: update: I'll be damned, it appears they *have* made `AsyncPipe` globally available now, so disregard the above. In that case, to debug this. subscribe to `obs$` in your component constructor and log each value in the subscription

Comment: Can you show a version of your method?

Comment: Also, can you log the results of `this.obs$`? And subscribe to it in code and log the output.

Comment: In your tamplate code you posted, your missing ` in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once. In my case angular did not render the template when the `async` pipe was used inside a `*ngFor` block.

I was including the minified version of Angular2.beta13 and I solved by including Angular with the beautified JavaScript.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36458828/2332293